# passing node.js query results to global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

i cant seem to figure out the correct way of passing the results of my query statement to a global variable so that i can dynamically configure my jsganntimproved chart. anyone have any thoughts on what im doing wrong?

in the code below, the console.log(taskItem) is blank, but if i move it to within the function setValue, it works as intended.

currently the taskitem variable is being defined as a const, but i have tried var and global. neither seem to get me what i need.

```
const taskitem = [];

con.query("SELECT * FROM projects", function (err, result, fields){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    setValue(result);
  }
});

function setValue(value) {
            if (value.length){
                        var i;
                        for (i=0; i<value.length; i++){
                                    taskitem.push({
                                                pID: value[i].Project_ID,
                                                pName: value[i].Phase_Description,
                                                pStart: value[i].Est_Start_Date,
                                                pEnd: value[i].Est_Comp_Date,
                                                pPlanStart: value[i].Est_Start_Date, 
                                                pPlanEnd: value[i].Est_Comp_Date,
                                                PClass: "ggroupblack",
                                                pLink: "",
                                                pMile: "",
                                                pRes: "",
                                                pComp: value[i].Billed / value[i].Spent,
                                                pGroup: "",
                                                pParent: 0,
                                                pOpen: 1,
                                                pDepend: "",
                                                pCaption: "",
                                                pCost: "",
                                                pNotes: "",
                                                pBarText: ""
                                    })

                        }
            }
}

console.log(taskitem);
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the time you are calling `console.log()`
The asynchronous code will set the value inside taskItem at a later point. 
Moving the `console.log(taskItem)` to inside the `function setValue` should fix it!

Comment: as for printing the results to the console, yes that does work, however, im trying to pass a variable that contains the results to another js page.

Comment: the problem you will have in that case is you will never know when the value has been set because the callback that sets the value is asynchronous. You will have to modify your code in such a way that synchronous code is not dependent on asynchronous output

Comment: ok that makes sense, do you know of any reference material i can refer to?

Comment: Unless I know the specific use case, this is the best reference : https://www.google.com/search?q=working+with+asynchronous+calls+javascript